# Find cells in dataframe where value is between x and y

Tags: python, pandas

I want all values in a pandas dataframe as True / False depending on whether the value is between the given x and y.

Any combining of 2 dataframes using an 'AND' operator, or any 'between' functionality from pandas would be nice. I would prefer not to loop over the columns and call the pandas.Series.between(x, y) function.

**Example**

Given the following dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{1:1,2:2,3:6},{1:9,2:9,3:10}])
>>> df
   1  2   3
0  1  2   6
1  9  9  10
```

I want all values between x and y. I can for example start with:

```
>>> df > 2
       1      2     3
0  False  False  True
1   True   True  True
```

and then do

```
>>> df < 10
      1     2      3
0  True  True   True
1  True  True  False
```

But then

```
>>> df > 2 and df < 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Laurens Koppenol\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 731, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `&` with parentheses (due to operator precedence), `and` doesn't understand how to treat an array of booleans hence the warning:

```
In [64]:
df = pd.DataFrame([{1:1,2:2,3:6},{1:9,2:9,3:10}])
(df > 2) & (df < 10)

Out[64]:
       1      2      3
0  False  False   True
1   True   True  False
```

It's possible to use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with `apply` but this will be slower for a large df:

```
In [66]:
df.apply(lambda x: x.between(2,10, inclusive=False))

Out[66]:
       1      2      3
0  False  False   True
1   True   True  False
```

Note that this warning will get raised whenever you try to compare a df or series using `and`, `or`, and `not`, you should use `&`, `|`, and `~` respectively as these bitwise operators understand how to treat arrays correctly

Answer (score 0):

`between` is a convenient method for this.  However, it is only for series objects.  we can get around this by either using `apply` which operates on each row (or column) which is a series.  Or, reshape the dataframe to a series with `stack`

use `stack`, `between`, `unstack`

```
df.stack().between(2, 10, inclusive=False).unstack()
```

[image]